# AngularJS global search not working

Tags: angularjs

Here's the global search function I'm trying to emulate: https://plnkr.co/edit/DRagFo?p=preview

Here's my attempt: https://plnkr.co/edit/n4aczq?p=preview

They are written slightly differently but I can't seem to figure out why the global search doesn't work. I believe it has to do with `$scope.parsedEntries.push(parse(content));` in `script.js`:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table','lrDragNDrop'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http',
        function ($scope, $timeout, $http) {

                        var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1O7M5gaEGlyE5gkOBARJrxJJMBYiTwz2THVjgbaTx9v8/od6/public/values?alt=json';
            var parse = function (entry) {
                console.log(entry);
                var description = entry.gsx$description.$t;
                var cause = entry.gsx$cause.$t;
                return {

                    description: description,
                    cause: cause
                };
            };
            $http.get(url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var entries = response.data.feed.entry;
                    $scope.parsedEntries = [];
                    for (var key in entries) {
                        var content = entries[key];
                        $scope.parsedEntries.push(parse(content));

                    }
                });

        }
    ]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to how you populate `parsedEntries` in script.js.

It has to do with the premature initialization of the directive st-table which depends on the value of `parsedEntries` which is a null reference in the beginning but gets populated later after the `$http.get`.

In the example everything works because the row data is all available to the st-table uppfront. You can say that is is the defect of the st-table however a small trick can get you going.

You may choose to defer the initialization of the st-table by introducing `ng-if="ready"` or something. Then set `ready=true` only in the `$http.get.then()` after the values are fetched.

```
<div class="table-container" ng-if="ready">
```

and the `then() function`

```
              $http.get(url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var entries = response.data.feed.entry;
                    $scope.ready = true;//populate this ready
                    $scope.parsedEntries=[];
                    for (var key in entries) {
                        var content = entries[key];
                        $scope.parsedEntries.push(parse(content));

                    }
                });
```

$scope.parsedEntries=[];

[Working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hjFLGV?p=preview)